# Restore MySQL database from Time Machine after updating MySQL Workbench and an update of MAC OS X

Tags: mysql, macos, timemachine

I have a localhost web environment on my Mac Book Pro running Catalina OS X. It runs a cms and uses MySQL. Because of import errors on a csv-file I updated MySQL Workbenc from, I assume, version 8.0.11 to version 8.0.18. Ever since I can't access my databases anymore and kind of desperate on how to get access to these databases. I do have a time machine running which backups the Macbook on a regular bases. The database I'm after is called 'develop'.

If I start MySQL workbench, I only see 'sysinfo', but no database related to my cms-project (desperate!) So, decided to reboot. Unfortunately Apple 'decided' to do an update on Catalatina.

In de folder /usr/local I do see 'mysql' which I think is a symbolic link to the folder *mysql-8.0.18-macos10.14-x86_64* Whatever mysql folder I look in, all data-folders seems to be 0bytes. Even the ones where Time Machine has a backup made prior to the update of MySQL Workbech.

What I really don't understand is that updating MySQL workbench implies no access to the database anymore.

[image: Folders in Finder]
[image: Folders as seen in terminal]

Any help is highly appreciated, since I'm desperate on the data I can't access.